# Blur effect in Windows 8 store application?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

How would you add a blur effect to a UI element (like a `StackPanel` or a `Rectangle`) in XAML for a Windows 8 Store application?

I am thinking of something like `BlurEffect` in WPF, [as demonstrated here](http://wpftoturials.blogspot.no/2010/07/visual-effects-in-wpf-blur-dropshadow.html). Any solution should be suited for animation or at least being updated multiple times per second.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/) library to blur and write the image.

It would probably look something like this:

```
// Blit a bitmap using the additive blend mode at P1(10, 10)
writeableBmp.Blit(new Point(10, 10), bitmap, sourceRect, Colors.White, WriteableBitmapExtensions.BlendMode.Additive);
```

Alternately, you could just write your own (or use code someone else wrote) similar to [this](http://notes.ericwillis.com/2009/10/blur-an-image-with-csharp/):

```
private static Bitmap Blur(Bitmap image, Rectangle rectangle, Int32 blurSize)
{
    Bitmap blurred = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);

    // make an exact copy of the bitmap provided
    using(Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(blurred))
        graphics.DrawImage(image, new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

    // look at every pixel in the blur rectangle
    for (Int32 xx = rectangle.X; xx < rectangle.X + rectangle.Width; xx++)
    {
        for (Int32 yy = rectangle.Y; yy < rectangle.Y + rectangle.Height; yy++)
        {
            Int32 avgR = 0, avgG = 0, avgB = 0;
            Int32 blurPixelCount = 0;

            // average the color of the red, green and blue for each pixel in the
            // blur size while making sure you don't go outside the image bounds
            for (Int32 x = xx; (x < xx + blurSize && x < image.Width); x++)
            {
                for (Int32 y = yy; (y < yy + blurSize && y < image.Height); y++)
                {
                    Color pixel = blurred.GetPixel(x, y);

                    avgR += pixel.R;
                    avgG += pixel.G;
                    avgB += pixel.B;

                    blurPixelCount++;
                }
            }

            avgR = avgR / blurPixelCount;
            avgG = avgG / blurPixelCount;
            avgB = avgB / blurPixelCount;

            // now that we know the average for the blur size, set each pixel to that color
            for (Int32 x = xx; x < xx + blurSize && x < image.Width && x < rectangle.Width; x++)
                for (Int32 y = yy; y < yy + blurSize && y < image.Height && y < rectangle.Height; y++)
                    blurred.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(avgR, avgG, avgB));
        }
    }

    return blurred;
}
```

To get the individual pixels for the second method see [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Metro-Style-lightweight-24589f50):

```
BitmapImage iSrc

var array = new int[iSrc.PixelWidth * iSrc.PixelHeight]

var rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, iSrc.PixelWidth, iSrc.PixelHeight)

iSrc.CopyPixels(rect, array, iSrc.PixelWidth * 4, 0)
```

Comment: Does this work if I do not have a `Bitmap`? What is the performance of running this at 60 fps in full screen?

Comment: Oh... you're trying to animate something?  I would suggest using DirectX.  You probably won't get the performance you want using controls.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229580.aspx

Comment: I will probably animate it, yes, but hopefully it will be so simple that it can be done without resorting to DirectX, as that would require a lot more work than we are comfortable with.

Comment: To animate it all you need to do is overlay the blurred and not blurred images and then slowly fade one in while fading the other out.

Comment: I am not animating between blurred and non-blurred. The shapes being blurred will change.

Comment: @VegardLarsen that sounds pretty processor intensive.

Comment: That is what I am afraid of. Which is why a solution working on a simple bitmap won't do.